# "Answer" Button Placement on Q&A/ Forum website

Tags: buttons

This is the example of user after posted the question in a forum website. They need people to answer their question. I have two layout which is **Version A and B**. May i know which one is the best in term of UX? and why?

[image]

Comment: Why not put it above share button? It then gone be in call to action place. https://www.awwwards.com/understanding-web-ui-visual-hierarchy.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with A. Consider the case where a question is long. If I read the whole thing the Answer button could be above the fold. Even for short questions, my attention is at the bottom of the question, so it makes sense for the next step to be down there within my area of focus.

You might want to look at how similar sites behave. Stackexchange places the answer field (not a button, thereby removing one click) below the question.

Comment: **If** discussion is in form of tree, answer field would be the hell annoying, because then they would split discussion in parts.